# What should I do when my question becomes entirely different after discussions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question about a library(say lib1) where I was getting an error. Later with comments from people and my own analysis, I found the issue in a different library(lib2) which was used along lib1.

1. Should I edit the question to ask about lib2? That would make answer and comments meaningless
2. Ask a new one, while linking in the original question?, In that case the original question becomes useless

It might also make sense to close question-1 as lack of research, but sometimes in complex scenarios, that might not be the case(I might have asker's bias)

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the question.  If it happened to you then it is just as likely to happen to somebody else.  So ask a question about lib2 and when you get it solved then go back to the first question and post the *this is what really happened* answer.

Comment: Hmm.. in my situation that does make sense

Comment: "make sense to close question-1 as lack of research" Lack of research is not a close reason, merely a reason not to upvote. Also, how can you be sure that is was a lack of research? Even with lots of research, questions can still turn out not very useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it becomes **entirely** different, and it's useless in its current state (no constructive or helpful info for future users), then you should *delete* it and post a new one.

If it's somehow useful, and you think future users might have similar flow, maybe you'll want to keep it alive and close it as a duplicate of the new question (I'm not sure though if they are really considered duplicates in such a case).

Comment: Hmm.. might not be dupIicate, I believe lack of research make sense

Comment: @MangatRaiModi Then I think it depends on the situation. If you think other users might come across the same issue, maybe it worth keeping it. Otherwise, just delete it.

Comment: "and close it as a duplicate of the new question..." I would not advice that. It seems that both questions would be rather unrelated towards each other, being about different libraries. Surely they wouldn't be duplicates. It may just be coincidence that the asker asked them both one after another.

Comment: In a case like this, shouldn't there be the option to 'fork' a question, where the original question might be considered 'stale' and the new version of the question then takes up the mantle? Deleting a question destroys the history behind its evolution to the current state as far as I am aware... But I might be missing something.

Comment: @Dshiz There is a feature for that. Just leave a comment on the original question explaining the situation, and linking to the new question. This preserves the "flow," as well as both questions. It also generates a link in the "Related" sidebar.